# Declarar variable global $scope en angularjs, junto a funcion?

Tags: angularjs

Quiero declarar la variable global `$scope`, pero estoy usando una funcion
llamada `WineCtr()`, pero cuando intento declarar el `$scope ,  ['$scope', function($scope){}` de esta forma, no me detecta el codigo.

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
  <h3>Categories</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="category in ctrl.getCategories()">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.filter[category]" />
      {{ category }}
    </label>

  </div>
  <hr />
    <input type="text" ng-model="busqueda" />
  <h3>Available Wines</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="wine in (ctrl.wines | filter:ctrl.filterByCategory) |filter:busqueda  as filteredWines">
    {{ wine.name }} <i>({{ wine.category }})</i>
  </div>
  <hr />
  {{holis}}
  <b>Number of results: {{ filteredWines.length }}</b>
</div>

</body>
</html>
angular.
  module('myApp', []).
  controller('Ctrl', WineCtrl,  ['$scope', function($scope){




}]);



function WineCtrl() {

  var self = this;

  // Variables - Public
  self.filter = {};
  self.wines = [
    {name: 'Apartamentos 1', category: 'Apartamento'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 2', category: 'Casa'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 3', category: 'Casa Apartamento'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 4', category: 'Apartamento'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 5', category: 'Hotel'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 6', category: 'Apartamento'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 7', category: 'Casa Apartamento'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 8', category: 'Hotel'}    
  ];

  // Functions - Public
  self.filterByCategory = filterByCategory;
  self.getCategories = getCategories;

  // Functions - Definitions
  function filterByCategory(wine) {
    return self.filter[wine.category] || noFilter(self.filter);
  }

  function getCategories() {
    return (self.wines || []).
      map(function (wine) { return wine.category; }).
      filter(function (cat, idx, arr) { return arr.indexOf(cat) === idx; });
  }

  function noFilter(filterObj) {
    return Object.
      keys(filterObj).
      every(function (key) { return !filterObj[key]; });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estas ejecutando tu código `javascript`(**AngularJs**) después del código `html`, es necesario que separes el código angular en un archivo diferente y llamarlo en el `head` para poder que te reconozca las funciones.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('Ctrl', WineCtrl,  ['$scope', function($scope){




}]);



function WineCtrl() {

  var self = this;

  // Variables - Public
  self.filter = {};
  self.wines = [
    {name: 'Apartamentos 1', category: 'Apartamento'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 2', category: 'Casa'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 3', category: 'Casa Apartamento'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 4', category: 'Apartamento'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 5', category: 'Hotel'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 6', category: 'Apartamento'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 7', category: 'Casa Apartamento'},
    {name: 'Apartamentos 8', category: 'Hotel'}    
  ];

  // Functions - Public
  self.filterByCategory = filterByCategory;
  self.getCategories = getCategories;

  // Functions - Definitions
  function filterByCategory(wine) {
    return self.filter[wine.category] || noFilter(self.filter);
  }

  function getCategories() {
    return (self.wines || []).
      map(function (wine) { return wine.category; }).
      filter(function (cat, idx, arr) { return arr.indexOf(cat) === idx; });
  }

  function noFilter(filterObj) {
    return Object.
      keys(filterObj).
      every(function (key) { return !filterObj[key]; });
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="Ctrl as ctrl">
  <h3>Categories</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="category in ctrl.getCategories()">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.filter[category]" />
      {{ category }}
    </label>

  </div>
  <hr />
    <input type="text" ng-model="busqueda" />
  <h3>Available Wines</h3>
  <div ng-repeat="wine in (ctrl.wines | filter:ctrl.filterByCategory) |filter:busqueda  as filteredWines">
    {{ wine.name }} <i>({{ wine.category }})</i>
  </div>
  <hr />
  {{holis}}
  <b>Number of results: {{ filteredWines.length }}</b>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```